# Retrieve JSON key and value

Tags: python, json

I am POSTing a .json object to my server with different keys attached.

```
ID, time, content
```

On my server I want to then wrap this again in another .json file with another APIs key and value formatting.

So... I want to store the key and value for 'content' 
Currently i can obtain the value for 'content by:

```
content = json_obj['content']
```

But this only returns the value. What is the syntax for storing the key and value in content?  The desirable outcome:

```
content = {'content' : "........."}
```

Comment: Do you want to *add* key-value pairs in your object?

Comment: Yes, I want content to store the previous .jsons content =
{'content' : '......'}
So essentially grabbing the key and value, only knowing the key("content")

The other .json object will contain key-value pairs, that's why I'm trying to get the key-value pair from this .json

Comment: You would generally do: `content["foor"] = "bar"` to update/add a new key-value pair. I hope this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON_obj here is acting as a dictionary, so you can use Python's `items` (Python 3+) or `iteritems` (Python 2.7) functions:

```
for k,v in json_obj.iteritems():
    foo = {k: v}
    # do something with foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks SuperSaiyan you triggered this thought.
Just create a new dictionary:

```
content = json_obj['content']
test_obj = {'content':content}
```

Could also:

```
test_obj = {'content':json_obj['content']}
```